# AxiosError, axios.post doesn't return the data in the console

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling, axios

The Axios post method in my code is not functioning properly, leading to an ERR_BAD_REQUEST error in the console. I am unsure of where the issue lies. The tutorial Im Following has the coder saying it works for him, but not for me. We have the same code because I have checked it multiple times!

```
const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await axios.post('/api/stores', values);

        console.log(response.data)
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};
```

`api/stores/route.ts`

```
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    try {
        const { userId } = auth();
        const body = req.json();

        const { name }: any = body;

        if (!userId) { 
            return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
        }

        if (!name) {
            return new NextResponse("Name is required", { status: 400 });
        }

        const store = await prismadb.store.create({
            data: {
                name,
                userId
            },
        });

        return NextResponse.json(store);

    } catch(error) {
        console.log('[STORES_POST]', error);
        return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
    }
};
```

Due to my confusion, I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Try with a full endpoint URL. Instead of using `/api/stores`, try with something like `https://yourhost.com/api/stores`

Comment: Also seems like you missed `/route` at the end of the endpoint, as you shared `api/stores/route.ts` file.

Comment: @0xKevin I tied this, but it didn't work

Comment: Pls try update your `response` code like below:
`const response = await axios.post('/api/stores', JSON.stringify(values), {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});`

Comment: Also, use `req.body;` instead of `req.json();`

Comment: @0xKevin You saved me man !!! Thanks so much, I just updated the response using your new code, it works, even i didn't change to req.body() becuase it says error: can not call an object with a value of null so i let as it is with req.json(), but the data it works on the console, thank you so much, appreciate your time

Comment: Sounds great! You're very welcome. Very glad to hear it could help you! Just wrapped up and posted the answer as well for a future reference.

Comment: @0xKevin For the axios.delete method, can it be written also like this : await axios.delete(`/api/stores/${params.storeId}`); Or in this way : await axios.post('/api/stores/${params.storeId}', {   headers: {     'Content-Type': 'application/json',   }, });, I need help

Comment: In a `axios delete` request, `Content-Type: application/json` header is generally not necessary unless you're sending a request body data. Seems like you're sending data in URL parameter, so I assume it would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed with the poster through comments, the below code change resolved the issue. Just wanna wrap up the solution and share it here for more folks who may have the same issue in the future.

You should make sure the `Axios` request is properly formatted and sending `JSON`. So, in the `onSubmit()` function, update the `axios` code block with the below:

```
const response = await axios.post('/api/stores', JSON.stringify(values), {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```